# Fuzzy Search in the Search API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

The Azure search api offers a fuzzy paramter for suggestions. like this:

```
https://blssuggestions.search.windows.net/indexes/cities/docs/suggest?api-version=2015-02-28&suggesterName=default&fuzzy=true&search=berlen
```

Would return "Berlin" as a result of berlen.

I can't find a documentation about this how to activate it in a normal search
setting there fuzzy = true seems to not change anything

```
https://blssuggestions.search.windows.net/indexes/cities/docs?api-version=2015-02-28&search=berlen&fuzzy=true
```

Comment: I was looking for this recently as well and wasn't able to come across anything helpful. From what I saw in the documentation the only way to get fuzzy search was to use the Suggestions API instead of the normal Search :( Will be watching this thread closely, hopefully someone else can show us a way to accomplish it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Update]: Please see the other responsed about using querytype=full as this response is no longer correct.

This is correct.  Fuzzy search is only available currently in the suggestions api.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call:

```
https://blssuggestions.search.windows.net/indexes/cities/docs/suggest?api-version=2015-02-28&suggesterName=default&queryType=full&search=berlen~
```

You were missing querytype=full and the tilde after the character that you want to execute fuzzy searches on.

Answer (score 1):

This is now in the preview version of the api:

```
https://{yourSite}.search.windows.net/indexes/{yourIndex}/docs?search={fieldToSearch}:{lookupValue}~&queryType=Full&api-version=2015-02-28-preview
```

Note the `~` and `queryType=Full`, both of which are required to force fuzzy matching.

Documentation is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt589323.aspx

CAVEAT: The fuzzy search is very fuzzy! i.e. `dog` will match any 3 letter word with only a single matched letter - `dim`, `now`, `bag`

I am trying to figure out how to tune and tweak but as it is still in preview the documentation is sparse.

UPDATE: I just re-read the documentation and it has since been updated with details of an optional distance parameter. I will investigate.