# Misspelling & synonym support for Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I've seen threads discussing both of these topics:

[Does Azure Search handle synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180405/does-azure-search-handle-synonyms)

[Fuzzy Search in the Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246973/fuzzy-search-in-the-search-api/31251224#31251224)

I see that Liam Cavanagh from the Azure Search team seems to be the guy who's answered queries on these threads.

Liam, are you able to confirm the following yet please:

1. When full synonym support will be added to Azure Search
2. Do you definitely plan to support synonyms with Azure Search, or is it possible that you will recommend that customers use the Bing Synonyms product instead?
3. Do you have any plans to go beyond fuzzy logic and offer more advanced support for misspellings (i.e. multiple letters missing or in the wrong order, which stemming won't cover)?

Many thanks,

Ali

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you got a negative vote as I think these are really good questions.  Let me answer your questions as best as I can:

1. You are correct that we do not have implemented "full synonym support", and this is one of the next most highly requested features, so it is definitely something that we have on our near term list although I am sorry that I can not provide a date yet.  If you have time, please cast your vote for this here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/8410635-support-custom-dictionary  In the meantime, there are "hacks" that can be done which are far from perfect, but can help get part of the way.   One example is to add a Collection field and then populate it with the relevant synonyms for each document.
2. I can not say that this is a "definite" feature, but given how often we hear this request, hopefully I have given you an insight into the likelihood that it will be implemented.
3. I am curious if you have tried our brand new Lucene Query Expression support (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt589323.aspx)?  There is some really great capabilities for fuzzy search and also capabilities to do things like RegEx searches, etc.  This is pretty awesome (IMO).

I hope this helps, and I am sorry that I am not yet able to give more definitive dates on some of these questions.

Liam

Comment: **UPDATE** We are (finally!) working on first-class support for synonyms. If you'd like to help us shape this feature and try it out as a early adopter, please email nateko at the usual Microsoft domain. Thanks!